# How to verify an exposed point in Banach space?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, linear-transformations

I read a paper "on operators which attain their norm" by J. Lindenstrauss, and have some problem in theorem 2 (p.142~143). First I give some definitions to be needed later.

Def)1. For Banach spaces X and Y, $B(X,Y)$ is a set of all bounded linear operator from X to Y.

2. An element T of $B(X,Y)$ attains its norm if $\Vert T\Vert=\Vert Tx\Vert$ for some $x\in X$
3. Let $C$ be a convex subset of a Banach space X. $x\in C$ is called an exposed point if there is $f\in X^*$, the dual of $X$, such that $f(x)>f(y) \forall y\neq x$ in C.

The situation is as follows:
$X$ is a Banach space such that every element of $B(X,Y)$ attains its norm, and T is an embedding from X to Y. I wanna show if $\Vert Tx\Vert=\Vert T\Vert$, then x is an exposed point of $S_X$.

(In fact it has more condition that the range of T is locally uniformly convex, which is omitted because it is related to the strong uniform convexity only, I think)

The proof is, choose $g\in Y^*, \Vert g\Vert=1$ such that $g(Tx)=\Vert Tx\Vert=\Vert T\Vert$ (and it skipped all other things).

I know for every $y\neq x$ in $S_X$, $g(Ty)\leq \Vert g\Vert\Vert Ty\Vert\leq\Vert T\Vert=g(Tx)$, but I cannot yields the strict inequality unless $g$ is one to one, so I'm stuck here. How can I do it?

Comment: Well, if you omit the uniform convexity of the range of $T$, and you skip the main part of the proof, then it would be expected to be hard to come up with the proof.

Comment: So, you mean locally uniform convexity does contribute to the proof?

Comment: Lindenstrauss writes:  "To conclude the proof we have only to show that if $T$is an isomorphism
(into) which attains its norm at a point $x$ and if the range of $T$ is locally
uniformly convex, then $x$ is a strongly exposed point of $S_x$. " - Do you think he would add in a condition if he did not need it?

Comment: I thought the condition locally uniformly convex is used only to show it is a strongly exposed point. Actually, I don't know how to connect l.u.c and the exposedness of the point. Can you give me a hint?

Comment: Oh, I understand. So the rest part already contains the strict maximum of the $f(x)$! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, it needs the locally uniformly convex (l.u.c.) condition.
Once we give this, then for $\Vert x_n\Vert\leq 1$, $g(Tx_n)\rightarrow \Vert T \Vert$ implies $\Vert Tx_n-Tx\Vert\rightarrow 0$ and hence $\Vert x_n-x \Vert\rightarrow 0$ by the injectivity of T. If $g(Tx)=g(Ty)$, take $x_n=y \forall n$ to conclude x=y.